# VBA code to compare path when file is opened

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compare file path when it is opening.

When open, compare if path is "\server\myfolder1\myfolder2\". If TRUE, do nothing. If FALSE, show MSGBOX and close file.

I tryed te following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim LocalFile As String
LocalFile = "\\Server\folder1\folder2"

If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> LocalFile Then
MsgBox ("This file is not original")

End If

Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Path

End Sub
```

It work when I make a copy to my local disc. But when I open from shortcut or mapping pointing to my network path, it doesn't work.

Tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert drive letter to full network path. Microsoft reference code [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/160529).

Here is the functional code to convert to full network path

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function WNetGetConnection32 Lib "MPR.DLL" Alias _
    "WNetGetConnectionA" (ByVal lpszLocalName As String, ByVal _
    lpszRemoteName As String, lSize As Long) As Long

Sub Test()
    If Not IsError(GetNetPath("Z")) Then
        MsgBox GetNetPath("Z")
    Else
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
End Sub

Function GetNetPath(ByVal DriveLetter As String)
    Dim lpszRemoteName As String * 255
    Dim cch As Long
    Dim lStatus As Long

    DriveLetter = DriveLetter & ":"
    cch = 255
    lStatus = WNetGetConnection32(DriveLetter, lpszRemoteName, cch)

    If lStatus& = 0 Then
        GetNetPath = application.clean(lpszRemoteName)
    Else
        GetNetPath = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If
End Function
```

> 

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim LocalFile As String
    Dim CurrentPath As String
    Dim CurrentDrive As String * 1
    Dim CurrentDriveMap As Variant

    LocalFile = "\\Server\folder1\folder2"
    CurrentPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    CurrentDrive = CurrentPath
    CurrentDriveMap = GetNetPath(CurrentDrive)
    If Not IsError(CurrentDriveMap) Then
        CurrentPath = CurrentDriveMap & Mid(CurrentPath, 3, Len(CurrentPath))            
    End If
    If CurrentPath <> LocalFile Then 
        GoTo NotOriginalHandler
    End If
    Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Exit Sub

NotOriginalHandler:
    MsgBox ("This file is not original")
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: how should that prevent opening the file by a shortcut ? i would appreciate it if you explain thank you very much.

Comment: if we can convert the drive to its full mapping path, then obviously it can be compared to the `LocalFile` string

Comment: i think this is not his Problem, as he statet the comparing works, but not for a shortcut, and since the shortcut is nothing other than a pointer to the exact same file with the same path this won't solve this, or will it ? anyway seems like really clean and good code ;)

Comment: `activeworkbook.path` always return the mapped drive path and not the full network address if the file is opened from the mapped drive folder. this is causing his logical test to fail... Thanks

Comment: ah, i think I understood the question wrong, sorry for the questions =) If the OP means it like you understood it, it is a really good answer, and i think it is like this so +1

Answer (score 0):

try this below

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ChDir ("\\172.16.5.4\BTS-Team")
    If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> CurDir Then
        MsgBox ("This file is not original")
    End If
    Range("B2").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Path
End Sub
```

Comment: how should that prevent opening the file over a shortcut. Doesn't the ChDir make the test obsolete, because the CurDir is always the same ? Please explain this to me if I don't understand it correctly. Thank you very much.

Comment: did you try the above code? chdir is nothing but change directory and curdir is current directory

Comment: yeah exactly, sorry i don't want to attack you, i want to understand, you Change the Directory to a specific Folder, and the test if active workbook.path is that Folder ? wouldn't  If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> "\\172.16.5.4\BTS-Team" be the same

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, yes you are correct. i just changed the current directory to server path and check the current file path with current directory.